# how to filter pivot table based on a specific cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a excel-vba to filter the Pivot Table based on a specific cell value in a cell which is a Vlookup value from another sheet. How do I do this? I have the lines to change the value according to the reference cell. The problem, the changes that occurs when the lookup value changes. the pivot no longer works.

Below is my code which I got from this link https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5325-excel-pivot-table-filter-based-on-cell-value.html

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Update by Extendoffice 20180702
    Dim xPTable As PivotTable
    Dim xPFile As PivotField
    Dim xStr As String
    On Error Resume Next
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xPTable = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable2")
    Set xPFile = xPTable.PivotFields("Locations")
    xStr = Target.Text
    xPFile.ClearAllFilters
    xPFile.CurrentPage = xStr
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The value is the Target range "A2" is a vlookup value which is dependent on the looked-up value.

If I type the vlookup function once, the changes occurs to the pivot table the problem now is that, once the vlookup is stated there's no need to retype it in cell as it will just change dynamically according to the look-up value and the index result row.

is there a way to declare vlookup function into the line automate the update?

Comment: This is because the [Worksheet.Change event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) does not occur when cells change via recalculation. Use the [Worksheet.Calculate event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(even)) for that case.

Comment: BigBen, Thank you for the response. I am not very proficient with VBA and currently still in my learning curve. Is it possible for you to show me how to write the Worksheet.Calculate event to work for my task?